# How to not have to specify Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a working hibernate setup using annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int id = 0;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email = "";

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="CREATED")
    private Date created = null;

    public User(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.created = cal.getTime();
    }

    public User(int id, String email, Date created) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "centaurus.hib.User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", created=" + created +
                '}';
    }
}
```

to make this work i have to have a entry(amongst others) in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<mapping class="centaurus.hib.User"/>
```

Otherwise hibernate throws error saying it has no mapping file.

alternatively when i create my persistent sessionfactory I can specify what classes are to be mapped.

The issue is, on other projects i have worked on I only needed to add a class and annotate it correctly for hibernate to use it. this is what i would like to do but don't know how. I don't want to have a list of classes in my hibernate config in addition to the annotated classes.

Comment: you can use annotation driven in your hibernate properties and have component scan for your class packages then all you need to do is just use mapping of one to one, one to many etc to drive your classes.

Comment: have you tried the pure JPA way? not hibernate specific stuff, only by using persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring for your Session Factory, you can specify the 'packagesToScan' property.

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyz.model" />
```

Comment: not using spring, using restx,  is this packages to scan specific to spring? it would appear so

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Hibernate `Configuration` class if you're wiring up Hibernate manually and call `Configuration#addAnnotatedClass(Class<?>)`.

Comment: Im currently using the configuration class to insert my credentials as i didn't want them in the xml file, I still use the xml fire for other options. but the idea was to remove the repetition for each class, rather than just moving it from the xml file to the sessionfactory creation class, essentially im looking for a hibernate or java (NOT SPRING) way of saying "include all annotated classes in xy.z package"

Comment: afaik, you'll have to write that yourself.